# Why is WebClient.DownloadString not getting all HTML text from a website?

Tags: c#, html

I am trying to retrieve all HTML text from a website so I can parse it for more stuff, and I am using `WebClient` and `DownloadString` but they are not returning the entire HTML text. Actually, it is even returning not the same HTML string I see when I hit F12 on the website.

Below is my code.

```
string htmlText;
using (WebClient client = new WebClient ())
{
    string htmlText = client.DownloadString("URL here");
}
```

Many websites use this code too, but it is not working for me. It won't return an error, though. It just won't retrieve the entire HTML text. It actually returns only a few % of the entire HTML.

Why does this happen? By the way, I am using an apartment search website, and I set some filters by location, the number of beds, and so on. I am trying to get the result page's HTML text, but the returned HTML doesn't even contain any apartment results, which I need for parsing..

Comment: Maybe they use some sort of API to fetch data with javascript. So you're downloading just a skeleton.

Comment: Is there a way to retrieve all HTML still?

Comment: Check your client-side javascript calls to their API & use those links to get this data.

Comment: Could you possibly give me a link showing how to do that? Is it included in the retrieved text?

Comment: If it is a dynamic website constructed in the client's browser you'd need some kind of browser-like client that executes the javascript in the webpage.

Comment: @J.Doe For [Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Tools/netzwerkanalyse/toolbar) and [Google Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/)

Comment: Use a headless browser. PhantomJS for example. You will be able to completely load a page (including external libraries/ dependencies) and then you can just download the HTML.

Comment: Thanks everyone! I actually tried adding "view-source:" at the beginning of the URL, and it shows more HTML text. But I cannot use WebClient with the URL that starts with "view-source:". Is there any way to read text from "view-source:html://....."?